# How can I overlap the Bottom Menu on top of the image and center it?

Tags: html, css

***I've already set the navbar, the image with the text, and the under part is going to be another menu. How an I first of all center the bottom menu and overlap it on the image as in the example? This is***
[How I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T05iA.png)

***On the other hand, this is***
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSQUq.jpg)

***I've only placed the code of the image and the under part since the code of the nav bar doesn't matter***

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
      <title>SerFin</title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,700|Prata" rel="stylesheet">
      <style>
        .HomeTabImage {
          background-image: url('Images/Chairs.jpg');
          width: 100%;
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: cover;
        }
      </style>
      <script>

      </script>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='Styles.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <header class="TopMenu">
        <nav class="TopSetup-Container">
          <img src="Images/Logo.png"/ id="Logo">
          <ul class="Menu">
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="Menu">
            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submission</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <article class="HomeTabImage">
        <h1> Service Finder </h1>
        <p> Let the opportunities begin </p>
        <p> Everything we do is driven by opportunities </p>
        <p> Search and provide services </p>
      </article>
      <article class="Services">
          <h3 id="HomeTabServicesTitle"> Here are the services provided by the community </h3>
          <div class="ServicesContainer">
          <ul class="Options">
            <li><a href="#">Univeristies<br></br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internships<br></br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Courses<br></br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jobs<br></br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services<br></br></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </article>
    </body>
  </html>
```

***CSS***

```
.HomeTabImage  {
  height: 340px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: normal;
}

.HomeTabImage h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: black;
}

.HomeTabImage p {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
}

/*Home Tab Info part*/
.Services {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}

.Services p {
  width: 640px;
}

.ServicesContainer {

}

#HomeTabServicesTitle {
  color: #828282;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #8B8C8C;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.Options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.Options li {
  list-style: none;
}

.Options a {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To center it, use `margin-left: 10%;`.

For overlapping try using `z-index: 2;`.